# Content type 1 to N relation view

Tags: views

First of all sorry if this is a basic question.

I have two content types "Category" and "Items"

I used "Entity reference" to link  both content types with each other.

Category contains "Category1, Category2, Categry3" as data.

Items contains 10 items 1 to 10.
Lets say each categoy contains 3 items.

How can I create a view of items grouped by categories?
For example:

1. Category 1:

   - Item 1
   - Item 2
   - Item 3
2. Category 2:

   - Item 4
   - Item 5
   - Item 6
3. Category 3 :

   - Item 7
   - Item 8
   - Item 9
   - Item 10

Thank you very much in advance for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your nodes titles for Category content types are *Category N* and for Item Content Type are *Item N*.

Create a view on content filtered by content type = category, then in views advanced section in  **Relationships** add relation on your entity reference field on category content type, then in the field section again add a title but in **Relationship** section of the field settings choose your relation created before and then Group Results by Category title field.

Comment: @HarjinderRandhawa you're welcome, we are here to help each other.